# Canon 6d, Canon 600 EX RT + Yongnuo YN622C TX + YN622C Flash wont fire..help

Tags: canon, flash, off-camera-flash, yongnuo

So as stated above I have this equipment: Canon 6D, Canon 600 EX RT, Yongnuo YN622C TX and YN622C Flash.

I want to take the Canon flash off the camera to have a simple portrait setup. I have the Yongnuo YN622C TX ETTL flash controller attached to the 6D, I have the trigger with the Flash (all channels A1) and the fire test works but when I focus and press the shutter the flash doesn't fire. I have the flash set to optical slave.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Your Canon 600 EX RT must not be set to slave mode. It should be mounted on the YN622C receiver in non-slave mode and it will fire when triggered through the hot shoe by the YN622C.

The YN622C TX transmitter and YN622C receiver become the master/slave and almost any type of flash can then be used off camera. Using a flash with a slave capability is overkill, and in your situation actually stops it from working.

Comment: thank you. This has majorly helped. Just took a few shots now and has worked! thanks for that